# Hierarchy data structure wih efficient query algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure to represent hierarchy class system in Java.
For example, I have three class, University,Major,Student, and their relationship looks like below.
[image]

Is there a efficient data structure that I can query with a path-like expression?
 For example, if the expression is CMU/cs/jake，then I get a instance of student class whose name is jake. As far as I know, the Trie could do this, is there any other option?

Comment: Are you looking for solutions in the Java API, or for quick "roll your own" suggestions?

Comment: The java collection do not provide this kind of DS, I am looking for a DS or any implementation suggestion.

Comment: It appears to me this is more about design pattern than data structure, [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) might be what you are looking for

Comment: It's a general tree, but I don't know of any implementation that takes that kind of query expression. I agree with chiwangc it's more a design pattern than a data structure. I immediately read this as "CMU is a Map of ArrayList" so `CMU.get("cs")` returns an `ArrayList<Student>` so it's really `Map<String, ArrayList<Student>>` for example. Otherwise, you could process XML and XPath for that type of expression query capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data fits into memory then you can implement this by putting a `Set` of children in each node of the hierarchy and then walking the sets to determine if the path is valid, for example

```
class University {
  private Set<Major> majors;
}

class Major {
  private Set<Student> students;
}

class Main {
  // true if the path is valid, else false
  public boolean query(University university, Major major, Student student) {
    return university.getMajors().contains(major) &&
      major.getStudents().contains(student);
  }
}
```

If you also need to walk the reverse path (i.e. if you need a bidirectional hierarchy) then you can put a `Set` of parents in each child.

This will run in average case `O(d)` where `d` is the depth of the hierarchy if you use `HashSets`, and in worst case `O(d * lg(n))` where `n` is the size of the sets if you use `TreeSets`.

If your data doesn't fit into memory then you may want to consider using a graph database, e.g. [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/).

---

Edit: You can make the code more generic at the cost of type safety by using `Map<String, E>` at each level, assuming that each object has a unique name or some other string identifier.

```
abstract class Hierarchical<E extends Hierarchical> {
  protected final Map<String, E> children;

  public boolean query(Queue<String> query) {
    String key = query.poll();
    if(key != null) {
      E value = map.get(key);
      if(value != null) {
        return query.isEmpty() || value.contains(query);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

class University extends Hierarchical<Major> {}

class Major extends Hierarchical<Student> {}

// special case for the bottom of the hierarchy
class Student extends Hierarchical<Hierarchical> {
  public Student() {
    children = null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean query(Queue<String> query) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("query should never reach this depth");
  }
}

class Main {
  // true if the path is valid, else false
  public boolean query(Hierarchial root, Queue<String> query) {
    return root.contains(query);
  }
}
```

This has the same runtime depending on whether you use a `HashMap` or `TreeMap`.  The query only consists of a queue of strings; at each level of the hierarchy the first string is removed, the `Map` is queried and the child node is returned if found, and the query proceeds on to the child node until the queue is empty (return true) or a node isn't found (return false).

Comment: it is a workable solution,but when the level of tree grow the code will be very verbose.